# Prototype error from c++ header

Tags: c++

I'm getting a prototype error: hanning.

```
cpp:26:1: error: prototype for 'int hanning::randomArray(int*, int*, int*)' does not match any in class 'hanning'
 hanning::randomArray(int *length, int *lowValue, int *highValue) {
 ^~~~~~~
```

However, I'm not sure what I've done wrong.  Here is a sample of the header and class file in question:

```
#ifndef HANNING_HPP
#define HANNING_HPP

class hanning {
public:
    int *randomArray(int *length, int *lowValue, int *highValue); //Problem 1

private:

};

#endif /* HANNING_HPP */
```

and now the class:

```
#include "hanning.hpp"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

// Problem 1: Random Number array
//Fills a dynamically allocated array with random numbers in a low to high range
hanning::randomArray(int *length, int *lowValue, int *highValue) {
    *length = (rand() % 25) + 25;
    *lowValue = -1 * (rand() % 5 + 5);
    *highValue = (rand() % 5) + 5;

    int *arr = new int[*length];

    for (int i = 0; i < *length; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % (*highValue - *lowValue + 1) + *lowValue;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

I don't know why I'm having this problem.  I'm using netbeans 8.2

Comment: Not related to your actual problem, but `int *arr = new int[*length];` is a bad idea. Use a `std::vector<int>` instead of the `int*` return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the return type `int *` in your function definition:

```
int *hanning::randomArray(int *length, int *lowValue, int *highValue) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm getting back into c++ and I'm rusty to say the least!

Comment: No worries, it happens!

Answer (score 2):

Your definition is the following:

```
hanning::randomArray(int *length, int *lowValue, int *highValue) {
```

There is no return type as you can see, while it should be `int*`.

If you are wondering why the error is not related to the definition, that's because a function with no return type is assumed to return an `int` so it's a valid declaration per se.